# Can GPIO.output be assigned to a variable? Raspberry PI

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Can `GPIO.output` be assigned to a variable like `light1ON = GPIO.output(18,HIGH)` in python? Because when I do this it automatically turns the light on even knowing I didn't call `light1ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
light1ON = GPIO.output(18,HIGH)
```

You actually call the `GPIO.output` as a function passing it two parameters, and assign the resulting value to `light1ON`.

If you want `light1ON` to be a function either `def` it as a function:

```
def light1ON():
   return GPIO.output(18,HIGH)
```

Or make it a lambda:

```
 light1ON = lambda : GPIO.output(18,HIGH)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was overthinking it all. haha